# Java 8:How to remove duplicates from the List based on multiple properties preserving the order

Tags: java, collections, java-8, duplicates, java-stream

I am trying to remove duplicates from a list of Student Objects based on multiple properties while preserving the order,As shown below i have list of student objects where we have multiple students with same name with varying attendence...i need to remove the duplicate student with same name and having studentAttendence as 100 while preserving the order.

```
Student{studentId=1, studentName='Sam', studentAttendence=100, studentAddress='New York'}
Student{studentId=2, studentName='Sam', studentAttendence=50, studentAddress='New York'}
Student{studentId=3, studentName='Sam', studentAttendence=60, studentAddress='New York'}
Student{studentId=4, studentName='Nathan', studentAttendence=40, studentAddress='LA'}
Student{studentId=5, studentName='Ronan', studentAttendence=100, studentAddress='Atlanta'}
Student{studentId=6, studentName='Nathan', studentAttendence=100, studentAddress='LA'}
```

**desire output After removing the duplicates:**

```
Student{studentId=2, studentName='Sam', studentAttendence=50, studentAddress='New York'}
Student{studentId=3, studentName='Sam', studentAttendence=60, studentAddress='New York'}
Student{studentId=4, studentName='Nathan', studentAttendence=40, studentAddress='LA'}
Student{studentId=5, studentName='Ronan', studentAttendence=100, studentAddress='Atlanta'}
```

What i have right now is only removing duplicates based on the name and not considering the percentage(100)...and also not preserving the order..any help is greatly appreciated.(Student supplier is a simple supplier function of list of students)

```
studentsSupplier.get().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getStudentName))
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toCollection(
                                () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Student::getStudentName))), ArrayList::new));
```

Note: Only duplicate records with studentName matching and percentage 100 must be removed,(Record Ronon has percentage 100 but there is no duplicate with the same studentname so that must not be removed)

Comment: the question is not clear. consider adding more cases such as student with only 100 percentage attendance.

Comment: It has to be handled through processing of a Stream?

Comment: The simplest would be to override equals & hash code, and you only need `LinkedHashSet` then it would be `List<Student> filteredStudents = new LinkedList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(students));`. Nice and simple. You cannot use sets to remove duplicates without proper equals and hashcode, which in your case should be build by name and attendance.

Comment: Is the `studentId` unique across the table(or this input list)?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to preserve order, obviously don't call `.sorted`, which messes with order.

More generally using streams here is complicated. Streams like it if the operation(s) you want to perform on each element within a stream are *independent* (do not need to look at anything except the one element being considered, i.e. no need to look at neighbours). That's not the case here.

If it is correct to remove *any* student with an attendence of 100 (by the way, that's a typo, the proper word is attendance), then all this stuff about 'duplicates' is a red herring, and all you need is:

```
list.removeIf(s -> s.getStudentAttendence() >= 100);
```

But if the idea is: Remove a record only if its attendence is 100+, **and** there is at least one other record in the list with the same name, it gets more complicated.

The primary issue is that **your data storage mechanism is not in an appropriate form for this job**. If you just stop with the lambdas, this is not hard. It helps to think about your list as consisting of 100 million entries. It is obviously not feasible for the entire stream op to keep the names of 100 million entries 'in memory'. You don't have that much memory. The datastructure (a `List`) also does not offer any fast lookups; there is no way to write code that answers the question 'how many records with studentName `Sam` is in this list?) without looping through 100 million entries which is a non-trivial job.

Thus, given the limits of:

- The input data is in `List` form.
- The input data is not already sorted.
- The output must keep the same order as the input.

Then the job is **impossible** on its face!

So, instead you need to accept that it isn't an easy one-liner, and that you need to first make alternative versions of the same data store that *do* store what you need.

Then there are additional concerns. In particular, what happens if you have 3 `Sam` students and each record has `studentAttendence = 100`? Should they ALL be deleted? Should none be deleted? Delete 2 arbitrary ones?

Often if you're having trouble writing an algorithm, the actual problem is that you haven't fully specified the behaviour you want, and thus your floundering is mostly down to you not fully understanding the problem, more than it is a coding issue.

Let's say the rule is simply: Delete all students with attendence = 100, but only if there is a record with the same name with an attendence below 100. If all records have an attendence of 100, keep them all, then:

```
List<Students> students = ...;
Set<String> dupeNames = students.stream()
  .filter(s -> s.getAttendence() < 100)
  .map(Student::getStudentName)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());

students.removeIf(s -> s.getAttendence() < 100 && dupeNames.contains(s.getStudentName());
```

Will do the job, and will do it quickly. (O(n), to be algorithmically specific: Making a set-based duplicate requires constant-time steps per student record, so O(n), and the removeIf call similarly requires checking each student, but only having to do constant-time work per step, because `.contains()` on a set is constant time assuming good hash distribution, which Strings usually have), thus, a constant amount of  O(n) operations means the whole operation is O(n): The time it takes grows linearly with how many students are in your input list (vs solutions that involve scanning the whole list every time you process a single entry in the list, which grows with the square of the input size).

Comment: Hi rzwitsertool,As you suggested the requirement is just to remove a duplicate record with same name and percentage as 100..any entry that matches the above criteria must be removed.

Comment: As I explained, that doesn't explain everything. Multiple people have given you examples of weird scenarios. What happens if you have 2 records with name = `Sam` and attendence = 100. And no other Sams. What now?

Comment: So if `dupeNames` contains `Sam`, would the `removeIf` here not remove all such entries with name `Sam` and attendance less than 100? Not really same as the desired output.

Comment: `dupeNames` doesn’t really contain dupe names but all names (with `getAttendence() >= 100`).

Comment: The final snippet had a bug in it; I fixed it now. The intent is: First fetch a list of all names for which there is at least one entry with attendence below 100. Then, remove all entries for which the name is on this list AND the attendence is 100+. It's one of a few different plausible takes on the requirement, which doesn't fully cover all edge cases.

Comment: Hi rzwiterstool , the snippet removes all the records that have percentage less than 100.Your previous code snippet was nearer to my solution except that it does not handle the scenario where the studentname is not duplicated but has studentAttendance percentage as 100 as in the case with the student name ronan. The studentName is  not duplicated but your snippet still removes it.  Anyway thanks for your help.This was your previous code snippet
.filter(s -> s.getStudentAttendence() >= 100)     students.removeIf(s -> s.getStudentAttendence() == 100 && dupeNames.contains(s.getStudentName()));

Comment: from your previous code snipped............List<Student> students = studentsSupplier.get();
        Set<String> dupeNames = students.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getStudentAttendence() >= 100)
                .map(Student::getStudentName)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        students.removeIf(s -> s.getStudentAttendence() == 100 && dupeNames.contains(s.getStudentName()));

Comment: That’s a slip, the `s.getAttendence() < 100` within `removeIf` should be `>= 100`. But it still doesn’t handle the case when two entries have the same name and `s.getAttendence() >= 100` (without an entry with the same name and `< 100`).

Comment: @Holger yes, because it is unclear what should happen in that case. I repeatedly pointed this edge case out; OP does not seem to understand their own question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `studentId` is uniqe as given in the example you coulduse the method `List.removeIf` with a BiPredicate accepting a student and the list of students.

```
BiPredicate<Student,List<Student>> pred = 
    (stud,list) -> list.stream()
                       .filter(s -> s.getStudentId() != stud.getStudentId())
                       .anyMatch(s -> s.getStudentName().equals(stud.getStudentName()) && stud.getStudentAttendence() == 100);

students.removeIf(stud -> pred.test(stud, students));
```

Comment: Thank you Eritrean.....your solution has covered my scenarios..thankyou very much....i don't have enough votes to up your solution....thankyou very much

Comment: @Robertishwick Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

You should Filter record like this:

```
studentList.stream().filter(s -> s.getStudentAttendence() != 100)
                .filter(distinctByKeys(Student::getStudentName, Student::getStudentAttendence))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

distinctByKeys method:

```
private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKeys(Function<? super T, ?>... keyExtractors) {
        final Map<List<?>, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        return t -> {
            final List<?> keys = Arrays.stream(keyExtractors).map(ke -> ke.apply(t)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            return seen.putIfAbsent(keys, Boolean.TRUE) == null;
        };
    }
```

After filtering

```
[Student [studentId=2, studentName=Sam, studentAttendence=50, studentAddress=New York], 
Student [studentId=3, studentName=Sam, studentAttendence=60, studentAddress=New York], 
Student [studentId=4, studentName=Nathan, studentAttendence=40, studentAddress=LA], 
Student [studentId=5, studentName=Ronan, studentAttendence=76, studentAddress=Atlanta]]
```

Comment: how is the output distinct based on keys? and what if `Ronan` had 100 attendance?

Comment: @Naman If `Ronan` had 100 attendence then it is removed

Comment: Don't know why someone gave down vote, this answer gives the desired output

Comment: haven't voted, but there is no duplicate name for `Ronan` in the input, so why would you remove it?

Comment: what if ronan has 100 percentage...it shouldn't be removed since it is not a duplicate...as there is only one entry with name ronan

Comment: Your solution does not handle the scenario where the studentName is not duplicated but studentPercentage is 100....in that scenario the record is being deleted even if it is not duplicated...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Integer> checkList = new HashMap<>();
Student [] buffer = studentsSupplier.get()
    .stream()
    .map( student -> 
    {
        checkList.compute( student.getStudentName(), (v,k) -> (v == null) ? Integer.valueOf( 1 ) : Integer.valueOf( v.intValue() + 1 ) );
        return student;
    }
    .toArray( Student []::new );
List<Student> result = buffer.stream()
    .filter( student -> (checkList.get( student.getStudentName() ).intValue() == 1) || (student.getAttendance() != 100) )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

This assumes that a record with an attendance of 100 remains in the list if it is the only one for that student.

The nasty version of the same code would look like this, but it is even less understandable:

```
Map<String, Integer> checkList = new HashMap<>();
List<Student> result = studentsSupplier.get()
    .stream()
    .peek( student -> checkList.compute( student.getStudentName(), (v,k) -> (v == null) ? Integer.valueOf( 1 ) : Integer.valueOf( v.intValue() + 1 ) )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
    .stream()
    .filter( student -> (checkList.get( student.getStudentName() ).intValue() == 1) || (student.getAttendance() != 100) )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether you abuse `map` or `peek`, both is “nasty”. And entirely unnecessary, as there is a collection of `Student` as starting point, so there is no need to collect them into another array. Instead, use a Stream operation like `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStudentName, Collectors.counting()))` which produces a `Map<String, Long>` in a clean way. And if you find your code unreadable, you’re on the right track. There is no need to invoke `Integer.valueOf(…)` or `intValue()` manually. Java has autoboxing since version 5. And arrays don’t have a `stream()` method.

Comment: @Holger – The collection is required as you cannot process a stream twice; I need to "tee" the stream into two results. The suggested call to `collect()` gives me only one output, the checklist, but the original stream would be lost. Only if `studentsSupplier.get()` would always return the same result, the buffer would be obsolete, but this would be an illegal assumption here. I corrected the missing `array.stream()` call.

Comment: So, storing the result of a single `studentsSupplier.get()` invocation into a local variable imposes such a challenge that you go the route of an unnecessary copy operation with discouraged side effects? And you still didn’t explain why you use manual boxing like `compute( student.getStudentName(), (v,k) -> (v == null) ? Integer.valueOf( 1 ) : Integer.valueOf( v.intValue() + 1 )` instead of just `compute(student.getStudentName(), (v,k) -> v == null? 1: v + 1)` or, even simpler, `merge(student.getStudentName(), 1, Integer::sum)`.

Comment: @Holger – What does `studentsSupplier.get()` return? The only thing we know about it is that it allows to call `stream()` on the return value. We do not know whether two consecutive calls of `stream()` will return the same result. So yes, storing the return value of `studentsSupplier.get()` is – based on the *currently* available information – a challenge. And usually its you who come up with obscure limitations that needs to be considered (implementation of `compare()`).

Comment: The question is about “remove duplicates from the List … preserving the order”, suggesting that the source is a list and has a meaningful order to retain. But if you don’t trust the source, you can simply use `List<Student> snapshot = new ArrayList<>(studentsSupplier.get());` Considering corner cases is fine, but building the entire software design on them is not. I don’t know which “obscure limitations” you are referring to, but the contract of `compare` is [well defined](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)).